# how to parse JSONArray

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to read this JSON lines but because it start with JSONArray i'm a little confused

JSON : https://pastebin.com/zbGXVLJv

I want to retrieve the contents of "img_src"

Kotlin:

```
 val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(url, Response.Listener(){
        var data = (JSONArray("photos"))

        for (itIndex in 0 until data.length()) {

            val item = data.getJSONObject(itIndex)
            val imgSrc = item.getString("img_src")

             _PhotoList.add(PhotosHubble(imgSrc))

        }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Also your response is jsonObject so you have to make a JsonObject request

Comment: you can use gson library https://github.com/google/gson, also this might be helpful for you: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @ADM, Exactly, no, it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Generate POJO from JSON` tool of Android Studio and generate different data class then use that data classes to pass in API calling